# Find the eccentric angle of a point on the ellipse $\dfrac {x^2}{4}+\dfrac {y^2}{5}=2$ whose distance from the center is $\dfrac {\sqrt {34}}{2}$.

Tags: conic-sections

Find the eccentric angle of a point on the ellipse $\dfrac {x^2}{4}+\dfrac {y^2}{5}=2$ whose distance from the center is $\dfrac {\sqrt {34}}{2}$.

My Attempt: 
The equation of ellipse is 
$$\dfrac {x^2}{4}+\dfrac {y^2}{5}=2$$
$$\dfrac {x^2}{8}+\dfrac {y^2}{10}=1$$
Length of major axis is $2b=2\sqrt {10}$
So, the semi major axis is of length $\sqrt {10}$
Now the equation of auxillary circle is 
$$x^2+y^2=10$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG the point$(P)$ be $x=\sqrt8\cos(\pi/2- t),y=\sqrt{10}\sin(\pi/2- t)$

Now we need $$34/4=(\sqrt8\sin t-0)^2+(\sqrt{10}\cos t-0)^2$$

Comment: I believe that the eccentric angle is generally defined w/r the major axis, so don’t you need to take into account that for this ellipse, it’s the $y$-axis instead of the $x$-axis?

Comment: @amd, please find the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

If $x^2+ay^2 = c$
and
$x^2+y^2 = 1$
then
$(a-1)y^2 = c-1
$
so
$y^2
=\dfrac{c-1}{a-1}
$,
$x^2
=1-y^2
=1-\dfrac{c-1}{a-1}
=\dfrac{a-c}{a-1}
$
so
$\dfrac{y^2}{x^2}
=\dfrac{c-1}{a=c}
$
and
$\dfrac{y}{x}
=\sqrt{\dfrac{c-1}{a=c}}
$.